# Kotlin multi platform project can't find module from XCFramework

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, xcframework

I created XCFramework MyFramework and try to connect it to KMM following the instruction https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/add-dependencies.html#add-a-framework-without-cocoapods

MyFramework.xcframowork was placed inside root of KotlinMultiplatform project

my .def file looks like:

```
language = Objective-C
modules = MyFramework
package = MyFramework
```

in build.gradle.kts file I write:

```
kotlin {
android()
iosX64 {
    compilations.getByName("main") {
        val MyFramework by cinterops.creating {
            // Path to .def file
            defFile("src/nativeInterop/cinterop/MyFramework.def")

            compilerOpts("-framework", "MyFramework", "-F/")
        }
        //val anotherInterop by cinterops.creating { /* ... */ }
    }

    binaries {
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    binaries.all {
        // Tell the linker where the framework is located.
        linkerOpts("-framework", "MyFramework", "-F/")
    }
}
```

But when I compile KMM project for iOS it writes me error:

```
Task :shared:cinteropEventBusTypesIosX64 FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: /var/folders/8h/_7cdkbh56b3fc72xbkjpk4nd218xjp/T/8209547019177661418.m:1:9: fatal error: module 'MyFramework' not found
```

I think I write wrong path in compilerOpts("-framework", "MyFramework", "-F/"), but could be another reason.

Answer (score 2):

On compilerOpts("-framework", "MyFramework", "-F/") you must write your path before your framework (write all path).

For example if your MyFramework.framework dir is on path:
/MyDisk/MyProyects/MyKotlinProject/MyFramework.framework
Your compilerOpts (and your linkerOpts) must be:
compilerOpts("-framework",
"MyFramework",
"-F/MyDisk/MyProyects/MyKotlinProject")

Comment: what about using a relative path?